# Would it be possible to see dust devils on Triton?

Tags: planetary-atmosphere, triton

Triton has an extremely thin atmosphere, but thick enough for haze and winds.

Plumes on Triton eject gas, which carries with it micrometer sized solid particles, which leave streaks on the surface areas down wind.

On Earth individual dust particles are usually invisible, but we can see a dust devil because there is a dense enough concentration of dust in the whirlwind.  Would it be possible for hypothetical dust devils on Triton to carry dense enough concentrations of dust to be visible to someone in a spacesuit or observing the surface with a telescope from orbit?

Comment: If the particles are around 1 micrometer, that's about the same as wood smoke on earth, but I have no idea how you'd figure out the concentration of particles.